# Using Html.HiddenFor Deletes all data in my model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Whenever I add Html.Hidden form in my Form Post it kills all the data in the Model.

Model -

```
public class ViewRemoveStep
{
    [HiddenInput]
    public PModel p { get; set; }
    [HiddenInput]
    public RemoveStep remvoveStep { get; set; }
}
```

Both fields in the model are models with several properties.

View -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RemovePStep", "PFilter", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horozontal" }))
 {
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.p.LOB)
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.remvoveStep.p, new { @id = "p", @name = "p", @type = "text", @placeholder = "P", @class = "form-control" })
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.remvoveStep.RemovedStep, new { @id = "RemovedStep", @name = "RemovedStep", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Remove multiple eg.(1,2,3)", @class = "form-control" })
     </div>

    <button class="btn btn-danger col-md-offset-4 center-block">Remove</button>
}
```

The ViewRemoveStep is coming into this view with the P already populated trying to get the RemoveStep populated from the form. No matter what if I add HiddenFor to the form, it posts a completely null model to the controller. Even the fields from the two typeable fields in the form are null. Take the hidden part away and the removestep fields return correctly, but the peril is null as you would expect.

Even if I use a HiddenFor on a string on the model its still returns all null. It's like using HiddenFor in anyway kills the entire model.

I can't figure out why.

EDIT

I've seen the same type of response twice now, and it doesn't seem to help. I changed my stuff to this

```
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("RemovePerilStep", "PerilFilter", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horozontal" }))
                     {

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.removeStep.peril, new { @id = "removeStep.peril", @name = "removeStep.peril", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Peril", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.removeStep.RemovedStep, new { @id = "removeStep.RemovedStep", @name = "removedStep.RemovedStep", @type = "text", @placeholder = "Remove multiple eg.(1,2,3)", @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.peril, new { @id = "peril", @name = "peril" })


                <button class="btn btn-danger col-md-offset-4 center-block">Remove</button>
                    }
```

The matching names aren't making any difference.

Comment: Start by removing your `new { @id = "p", @name = "p", @type = "text" }` from both `TextBoxFor()`. Under no circumstances do you ever attempt to change the `name` attribute (and in your case it does absolutely nothing anyway - fortunately), and the method already adds the correct `id` attribute and the `type="text"` attribute

Comment: But you have not even shown your controller methods (which are clearly wrong) so this question is unanswerable as it stands. Show the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the name of your DOM field match to the property of the model your controler is waiting for.

Actually, your input field has `@name = "RemovedStep"` and it doesn't match with the model.

In your Model you have `public RemoveStep remvoveStep { get; set; }` your name as to be something like `@name = "remvoveStep.fieldName"`

If you don't specify a name, it is generated with the good matching name.

Comment: I just tried what you said. I changed the @names to match the properties. No change, still a null model.

Comment: Yes. It is purely based on the the fact that HiddenFor is there. Take away the hiddenFor and the two fields bind correctly. Add the HiddenFor and both models in the view model become completely null.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.remvoveStep.p, new { @id = "p", @name = "p", @type = "text", @placeholder = "P", @class = "form-control" })
```

you are setting the `id` and `name = p`, but in reality it should be `removeStep.p`

When the form post back ASP.NET sees a parameter called '`p`' with text = something. So it tries to look for property p in your model and it sees that `p` is actually a `PModel`, but the text is just a `string` instead of a valid json so it just skips that property. Thus the model is `null`.

just do `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.remvoveStep.p)` and it should fix the problem

Comment: I tried your example and it didn't make a difference. I added your suggest in the edit.

Comment: @MartinMcfry remove all the `@id` and `@class` and try again